# Magento google checkout integration issue 404

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I'm trying to integrate google checkout with a magento site and get the following error in the Integration Console:

```
We encountered an error trying to access your server at 
https://www.domain.co.uk/googlecheckout/api/ 
-- the error we got is Sending failed with HTTP response
code: 404. Response body was: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title> <style type="text/css">
<!-- body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
 h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF; background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
 .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} -->
</style> </head> <body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content"> <div class="content-container"><fieldset> <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
<h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
</fieldset></div> </div> </body> </html>
```

As far as I can tell, it's not actually a 404 error as I can do the following:

```
 wget --post-data=blah https://www.domain.co.uk/googlecheckout/api/
 --10:58:43--  https://www.domain.co.uk/googlecheckout/api/
       => `index.html'
 Resolving www.domain.co.uk... 192.168.1.117
 Connecting to www.domain.co.uk|192.168.1.117|:443... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
 10:58:43 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Now the 503 error there actually relates to me not sending any `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` with wget, so it dies on this line `strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], " ") + 1)));` in `googleresponse.php`. **This isn't the problem.**

I have tried both https://www.domain.co.uk/googlecheckout/api/ and https://www.domain.co.uk/googlecheckout/api in both wget and Google Checkout settings callback URL with the same results.

I've made sure that `always_populate_raw_post_data = On` is set, and it's showing up correctly in `phpinfo()`.

I've tried debug mode On and Off in Google API settings within Magento.

The checkout process was working correctly on a dev domain using the sandbox mode.

I've tried all of the things that I could find with google searches. Any other options would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
It looks like that response is from an IIS server. The server that this site is now running on is Apache. Could Google still be accessing the old server? DNS was updated over 15 hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the server logs on the old and new servers to see which one Google made the request to.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out in chat. Put me on the right track to working out why it's not working.

Comment: Turns out Google was accessing the old site, because the DNS server was set with a TTL of 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

That original error from google is an IIS 404 page, not an apache 404 page, so it seems as though google is looking at a different web server.